# norm package: how do I combine separate characters?

Tags: string, unicode, go, character, composition

I was expecting to get 밥 and 좋은, for the last two output.

for the output but This does not "combine" any of the following.

This package does not do anything.

Could anybody tell what I did wrong in this code? I would greatly appreciate it.

```
import "code.google.com/p/go.text/unicode/norm"
import "fmt"

func main() {
  str := "ㅈㅗㅎㅇㅡㄴ"
  fmt.Println( string( norm.NFD.AppendString(nil, "앉") ) )
  fmt.Println( string( norm.NFC.AppendString(nil, "바ㅂ") ) )
  fmt.Println( string( norm.NFC.AppendString(nil, str) ) )
}
```

The package is from here

go get -u code.google.com/p/go.text/unicode/norm
http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.text/unicode/norm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does something. If you observe the output from your first operation:

```
fmt.Println( string( norm.NFD.AppendString(nil, "앉") ) )
```

You can see that it has successfully made a decomposition of your string, returning three code points in place of your original `앉` character. The first being `ᄋ`:

```
U+110B (HANGUL CHOSEONG IEUNG)
```

While not visibly, this differs from the `ㅇ` character in your `str` variable:

```
U+3147 (HANGUL LETTER IEUNG)
```

If you would make a composition of the characters you get as an output from the NFD, you would indeed end up with 앉 again.

**EDIT**

The letters in your `str` variable uses [Hangul Compatibility Jamo](http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/hangul_compatibility_jamo) characters which are only meant for backwards compatibility, but lacks semantic properties. If you want it to work, you should use the [Hangul Jamo](http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/hangul_jamo) block instead.